# How can I get the text above this image to also wrap around the image

Tags: css

Like i've done with the paragraph text below, I want the heading to also wrap around the image.

I'm using a polygon for the shape-outer.

The bottom is wrapping perfectly fine. I can't figure out if the problem is with the H1 or the image. Positioning differently doesn't help, floating doesn't do anything. I'm a bit lost.

[image: explainer]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800');

.__centered {
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
 }
OR

.__centered {
  grid-column: 3 / -3; 
 }

.l-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1196px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.l-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.l-grid--col {
  grid-column: auto/span 6;
}

.l-grid--col-2 {
  grid-column: auto/span 2;
}

.l-grid__centered {
  grid-column: 3 
}

img.testing {
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 120px, 0 260px, 590px 100px, 590px -30px);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 120px, 0 260px, 590px 100px, 590px -30px);
  float:left;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: black;
    margin: 0 100px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 100px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color:#838383;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="l-wrap">
   <div class="l-grid">
  <section class="l-grid--col-2 l-grid__centered">
   <h1>Magna faucibus, eu efficitur lorem efficitur.</h1>
   <img class="testing" src="http://i.imgur.com/rRnHfxv.png" alt="Sidekick" />
   <p>Aenean sit amet bibendum nisi. Praesent aliquet quis augue nec interdum. Mauris venenatis et lacus id finibus. Sed pharetra cursus aliquam. Fusce pellentesque volutpat augue, non lobortis purus pulvinar ac. Ut lacinia volutpat lacinia. Proin mauris tortor, mollis eu dui non, efficitur fermentum eros. Etiam dapibus tristique molestie. Mauris lacinia lorem in magna faucibus, eu efficitur lorem efficitur.</p>
  </section>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this can be done with CSS alone. I'd love to be proven wrong though. I might play with some more ideas later but everything I could think of didn't work.

Comment: That's a pain. I was starting to think the same.